# remove a sublist from a tcl list if you have duplicate items in the sublist

Tags: list, tcl, duplicates

I have a tcl list of lists like this :

```
{ a b 2 3} { x y 2 5} { t k 4 5 } { w x 1 2}
```

i want to check by a particular index of the sublist if I have duplicate items in the sublists ( here index 2 of first two sublist),
and remove that sublist, here I have 2 @ index 2 of first 2 sublist, so I want to remove the second sublist
final list will be

```
{ a b 2 3}  { t k 4 5 } { w x 1 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably to use a dictionary to do the duplicate removal (which means we also get reasonable maintenance of order, which an array-based method probably wouldn't do without a lot of extra work). The main complication is that we need to process things in reverse as we're looking for the *first* items and not the *last*:

```
proc removeDupsByIndex {list index} {
    set d {}
    foreach item [lreverse $list] {
        dict set d [lindex $item $index] $item
    }
    return [lreverse [dict values $d]]
}

set input {{ a b 2 3} { x y 2 5} { t k 4 5 } { w x 1 2}}
set output [removeDupsByIndex $input 2]
puts "input: $input\noutput: $output"
```

Comment: thanks but lreverse command is not working for me , I ma getting unknown command error

Comment: What version of tcl are you running? `set version [info patchlevel]`

Comment: You're still on 8.4 (or before!)? Get with the program, man! Upgrade to a version that's currently *actually supported* by its developers...

Comment: A couple of years ago, I was working with a system that had 8.0 embedded. It's pretty sad when you gaze longingly at 8.2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Donal's answer, a version that should work in older Tcl versions

```
proc removeDupsByIndex {list index} {
    set result {}
    array set seen {}
    foreach item $list { 
        set key [lindex $item $index]
        if { ![info exists seen($key)] } {
            set seen($key) 1
            lappend result $item
        }
    }
    return $result
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the response , the answer by jackman works fine.

Comment: @noname I suggest you accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mid reordering the elements, you could use [`lsort`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.htm):

```
lsort -unique -index 2 $list
```